# How to use windowed aggregations in spark using java apis, while performing map operation on a dataframe?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Same as the topic - How to use window function in spark using java apis, while performing map operation on a dataframe ?

Suppose, I am performing this map operation -

```
LongAccumulator accum1 = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();
LongAccumulator accum2 = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator();

Dataset<String> deviceNamesByDF = deviceDF.map(
                (MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> {
                    if(row.getString(0).equals("nexus4_1")){
                        accum1.add(1);
                    }
                    else if(row.getString(0).equals("nexus4_2")){
                        accum2.add(1);
                    }
                    return "Model: " + row.getString(0);
                },
                stringEncoder);
```

Now, I want this operation to be windowed , just like we find the occurence of some cols using windowed aggregation like this -

```
Dataset<Row> windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
  functions.window(words.col("timestamp"), "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
  words.col("word")
).count();
```

How do I achieve this ?? How do I perform map operation on windows of data ??